# How do databases fits inside the Docker architecture?

Tags: sql-server, database, docker

I'm hearing a lot in the past years about docker, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how the DB part fits in. I understands that apps & services can live inside a docker container which hold binaries and required libs. but what about the database?

1. If I have an existing 60 Gigabyte sql server Database with replication & BI, do I need to move all the Data inside a container? or only the DB schema?
2. How integration tests will run in such environment? I keep hearing you can "spin up" a database inside a container, run your tests & discard it. really? it sounds a bit complicated to create the whole schema & data that will be required for your tests to pass.

Answer (score 0):

First, a database is nothing more than a stateful application. The approach to dockerize a database is not that different from dockerizing an application. You still need to copy the binaries and the dependencies in a container.

Now running a database inside a container will isolate the database in the container's filesystem. If the current data is needed by the database, it has to be moved/imported to the container.
Baking the data in the container is generally not good practice. The container image is better kept immutable and portable. It is better to import needed data to the database after starting the container.
Thus it is recommended to start a fresh db container and import data form your current database to the new one.

For your second question, starting a database using docker is pretty easy. It mostly reduces to running one `docker run`  command. Moreover, most popular databases, for instance [sql-server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server), are already containerized. This is great for integration tests that depend on having a database when running.

Traditionally, integration tests that depended on a database, were handled by starting some sort of an in-memory database that the test starts. This was needed because spinning an actual database instance on the machine is not trivial and requires the database application to be installed on the machine. This makes the test less portable to new machines.

Docker solves these problems by providing an easy way to start a db instance that is isolated. By running very few commands, the db instance can be started by the test and cleaned after the test finishes.

Comment: Regarding baking in the data - yes it's generally bad practice for live databases. For test automation and development, it can be glorious.

Comment: @bluescores Agree. I think for tests, baking the data in the image is the way to go.

Comment: guys, won't the images be very large in this case? a working db instance with testable data may require dozens of Gigabytes

Comment: @Ofir Yes, the images would be very large. Our test/dev data instance is curated to be under 100MB, which makes it very quick to download and run. Of course, traditional test automation methods - putting the system into a known state before executing the test - also works.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options to enable database containers with data.   First, as you note, is "in container" (local) data.   This works well for smaller data sets, up to 2-3 GB, but is impractical for a 60 GB environment due to storage consumption and simple time required to create copies.   A second option is to clone (copy) the data and create an external mount point.   This works reasonably well if sufficient fast storage is available (flash?).    Third is mounting to snapshots or cloned images, which can be done with NetApp, Pure, and other SANs.   The snapshots in this case support full read/write capabilites, and should support your use case nicely, but do involve some scripting to make work.